# SQL : how to use IN keyword with prepared statement for range replacement using Java

Tags: sql, prepared-statement

```
String sql = "select * from file_repo_index where id in (?)";

PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

ps.setString (1, toCommaSeparatedList(repoIdList));     

ResultSet result = ps.executeQuery();
```

---

```
public static String toCommaSeparatedList(Collection col);
```

---

I have to use the query as

```
select * from file_repo_index where id in ( 1,2,3,4 )
```

But it gives following error in executeQuery() statement

java.sql.SQLException: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '213304,213305,213307' to data type int.

I can use it like

```
String sql = "select * from file_repo_index where id in ("+toCommaSeparatedList(repoIdList)+")";

Statement ps = conn.createStatement();

ResultSet result = ps.executeQuery(sql);
```

But I want to use the PrepareStatment method. How can I do it. ??

Answer (score 2):

You should create your prepare statement placeholders based on your values, for instance:

```
String sql = "select * from file_repo_index where id in (";
//append ?, in above sql in a loop
//Then prepare statement.
```

This will involve a bit of extra coding, but i think this is the only way to force using PreparedStatement.

Answer (score 0):

If You want to use IN keyword then inside the brackets you have to put like

```
('213304','213305','213307')
```

as seperate variables and dont combine in a single "single quotes the entire values" and also in the select statement

```
 String sql = "select * from file_repo_index where id in ("+toCommaSeparatedList(repoIdList)+")";
```

Change the double quotes to single and try

```
('+ toCommaSeparatedList(repoIdList) +')";
```